# Check if user is administrator/Gamemaster [MYSQLI]

Tags: php, mysqli

i've been making a php/html/mysqli web based game for 3 days and did a good progress but it's hard to enjoy web programming when you can't find a answer or you aren't smart enough to find it... I'm using mysqli/php and i can't understand, how to check if user is [GAMEMASTER] or [ADMINISTRATOR]. My Database is perfectly working, but i don't know how to write a code who will detect that user is admin or "GM". Would it be possible if i would use code something like this? Thanks

```
public function gamemaster($uid){
$sql6="SELECT gamemaster FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
$result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql6);
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $user_data['gamemaster'];
}
```

I can't do remaining progress without knowing this answer.

Comment: Add level row in your users table and store user levels. ex: admin > 1 and gamemaster > 2.

Answer (score 1):

if you have so many roles and if you want to manage from admin side create new table called roles and build relationship between roles and users table.

if you have one or two roles then add one column role, then give some flags for each role i.e 1 is admin,2 is GM, 3 is user like this while saving to database based on permission save 1,2,3 values to role. 
to get roles
`$sql6="SELECT roles FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";` this one will work

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: This is the best way as you can add more permissions to the table and functions relating to them later as you build.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function gamemaster($uid){
$sql6="SELECT gamemaster,level FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
$result = mysqli_query($this->db,$sql6);
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $user_data['gamemaster'];
echo $user_data['level'];
}
```

Comment: This will show user level but i want to show it if user gamemaster.

Comment: define levels in mysql table when user creating, then verify when user logging you will get level of user.